# Paypal use of stored card - security code (cvv2)

Tags: paypal

I'm thinking of using Paypal's card storage service:

https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/store-a-credit-card/#use-a-stored-credit-card

As per the documentation, seems like in order to process a payment with an already stored card you just need to send the card_id.

I would expect the Security Code to be sent as well as part of the request however I haven't seen anything related to it in the docs.

Does this mean that Paypal would process the payment just with the stored card id?

This way doesn't seem too secure from a user perspective.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure you found an answer by now, but it's against credit card standards (PCI-DSS) to store the card security code (CVV/CSC/CVC) in any form. If the data is compromised, the person(s) who have this data are confirmed as an authorized user having the card in their possession during a digital transaction.

It is a fraud verification check that is only done by the issuing bank to prove you have the card in possession. If anyone has this information other than the cardholder, the cardholder may be liable for all purchases. In the event your purse or wallet is stolen, you would need to report it or be deemed liable for any activity.